# getting an error in unboxing in c# stating name does not exist in current context?

Tags: boxing, unboxing

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter id");
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("enter name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("price");
            int price = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("enter quantity");
            int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            product_demo p1 = new product_demo(id, name, price, quantity);
            p1.diplay();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    public class product_demo
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public int price;
        public int quantity;
        public product_demo(int id, string name, int price, int quantity)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            object o1 = id;
            object o2 = name;
            object o3 = price;
            object o4 = quantity;

        }
   
        public void diplay()
        {
            int j = (int)o1; 
            Console.WriteLine("id :");
        }
    }
```

getting an error while unboxing in display function. boxing is done in product_demo constructor. one more question ; can we define boxing outside any constructor or methods, directly in body of class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created `object o1` in the constructor of `product_demo` and therefore it exists only within that scope. You need to have your objects within the class (Similar to where you have placed your other variables such as `int id`, `string name`, etc.